# Hibernate's FetchType.LAZY not working with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I am building a REST-like API using Spring. I have encountered a problem in which using FetchType.LAZY along a @ManyToOne relationship causes an error when retrieving an entity using a JPA Repository.

Here’s a simplified, compilable version of my code:

**A.java:**

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private B b;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

**B.java:**

```
@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String someData;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSomeData() {
        return someData;
    }
}
```

**ARepository.java:**

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {}
```

**AController.java:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("a")
public class AController {

    private final ARepository repository;

    AController(ARepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    A one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

**data-h2.sql:**

```
    INSERT INTO B (id, some_data) VALUES (1, 'Very large data I do not want to load unless explicitly requested');
    INSERT INTO A (id, b_id) VALUES (1, 1);
```

I call the endpoint with `curl -v http://localhost:8080/a/1` (Windows CMD)

Response expected: `{"id": 1}`

Response received instead: `500 Internal Server Error`

Server console error:

```
ERROR 8484 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

If I remove `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` the call returns successfully, but the JSON includes all data from `B`, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: hello,  have you tried to use this annotation    @JsonIgnore on B in the class A or create a new Dto class for A  ? you can also dsiable this error with this : spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS = false

Comment: JPA mappings handle serialization to/from the database, while Jackson handles it to/from JSON - they are completely independent. Your error common, and occurs because Jackson is serializing everything in your object graph as you've not told it any different - and it does so after the transaction has been closed. While the error is a strange one, it likely has to do with spring settings. As others have mentioned, use JsonIgnore or other options to signal Jackson what should and should not be serialized in your model -remember you'll have to handle these relationships yourself though.

Comment: @CheikhHAIBALA I tried using JsonIgnore and I got the intended result. But I still don't know why Jackson produces an error without this annotation. Why is Jackson trying to serialize something that should not be loading in the first place? Is there any point in using FetchType.LAZY as long as I'm using Jackson as a JSON parser?